# Contract interpretation

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, oxford-comma

To be eligible for holiday pay the employee must meet the following requirement: the employee must have worked the last scheduled day before, and the first scheduled day after a holiday except when the employee has been granted pre-approved absence. *For the purpose of this article, a pre-approved absence is defined as a scheduled vacation day, personal day, compensatory day or an excused sick day.*

The last sentence is what I would like help interpreting.

This sentence could have contradictory meanings . 
On one hand a pre-approved absence means that all four types of absences must be scheduled. 
For instance: pre-approved absence is defined as a scheduled vacation day, a scheduled personal day, a scheduled compensatory day or a scheduled excused sick day

Or on the other hand it could be interpreted as such:( meaning only the vacation day is to be scheduled)

Pre-approved absence Is defined as a scheduled vacation day, a personal day, a compensatory day  or an excused sick day

I am also puzzled by the use of "or" rather than "and"  and am wondering if they affect the sentences meaning

From the way this sentence originally reads which is correct?

Comment: It's ambiguous.

Comment: Yeah, it's not great. But I get the feeling the person who wrote it thinks it's top work... I read it that 'excused sick days' are 'pre-approved' to *be* pre-approved. They got their wires crossed  :)

Comment: What is meant is probably that vacation days, personal days, and compensatory days have to be scheduled (beforehand) and sick days have to be excused (afterward).  That isn't what's written, but it seems to be as close to what's written as any reasonable rule can get.

Comment: It's not at all rare for native speakers to run on their lists instead of properly separating things after with comma and/or "and" or "or".

Comment: Luckily, it means all you have to do to turn a three-day weekend into a five-day weekend (supposing the holiday is on Monday, and you have available "sick days") is to work Friday, then call in sick on Tuesday and Wednesday. Of course, if your supervisor requires a doctor's note to grant you "excused" sick time, this won't work. Tell him you just had the flu and didn't need to see the doctor (but that you were miserable all weekend and didn't get to enjoy the holiday.)

Answer (score 1):

No, they did not write this clearly. An appropriate rendering woul go something like this:

- For  the purpose of this article, a *pre-approved absence* is defined as a scheduled vacation, personal, or compensatory day **,** or an excused sick day.

But it is increasingly common for native speakers to write without poperly separating lists from items which are not part of the list, even those that grammatically *could not be* part of the list (not that I would consider such usage *correct*, but it happens a lot.)

For example:

- This appliance is attractive, easy to clean, and will be a valuable addition to your kitchen.  (s/b ..attractive and easy to clean, and...)
- This offer is available only on Saturday, Sunday, and will not be repeated.
- We like to travel to Mexico, Jamaica, Hawaii and we go every year.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative rendering:

To be eligible for holiday pay, an employee must meet both of the the following requirements:

- The employee must have worked the last scheduled day before the
  holiday.
- The employee must have worked the first scheduled day after a
  holiday.

Please note that, for the purpose of this article these exceptions will apply;` if an employee has an excused sick day or a pre approved absence, that employee will be considered to have worked on the day of the exception.  A pre-approved absence is defined as a scheduled vacation day, personal day or compensatory day.