# What does the term "scheduled" modify in the following sentence:

Tags: grammar, modifiers

For the purpose of this article, a pre-approved absence is defined as a scheduled vacation day, personal day, compensatory day or an excused sick day.

Comment: Didn't you ask this on August 1st?   http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/263908/contract-interpretation

Comment: Indeed I did.  I am seeking additional insight. Thank you for providing the full context.

Comment: If this isn't a duplicate question, it's the closest thing to it.  But I'lll refrain from flagging.

Comment: To me, the intended meaning is very clear: of course your employer prefers to have you pre-schedule your vacation, personal and compensatory days so they can be pre-approved. The only exception is that they'll let you count an excused sick day as if it were a "pre-approved absence", because they understand you couldn't know you were going to be sick.

Answer (score 1):

*Scheduled* modifies *vacation day*, *personal day*, and *compensatory day* since the three latter items are placed in sequence with no interrupting conjunction (such as the *or* right after).

To reword the sentence:
*...A pre-approved absence is defined as a  scheduled vacation day, scheduled personal day, scheduled compensatory day...*

Comment: I believe the intent was for it to modify all the items in the series, however I agree it only modifies "vacation day".  How would you suggest rewording it to include all items?

Comment: @user131366 _Scheduled_ actually does modify all three items, so no rewording is necessary.

Comment: I think you could write "scheduled vacation, compensatory, or personal day, or an excused sick day" which would be less elegant but perhaps a tad clearer.

Comment: In regards to the "excused sick day" aspect; would u agree the term "scheduled" does not modify it due to comma placement?

Comment: Syntax can take you only so far.  To be sure of the meaning, you'll have to ask the knuckleheads who run your HR department.  If all the items are scheduled write, "A pre-approved absence is any scheduled day not worked whether such days are vacation days, personal days, compensatory days, or excused sick days."

Comment: @user131366 Every time you write “u”, a kitten goes without food somewhere.

Comment: @deadrat this is a Collective Bargaining Agreement issue. So it is us the Union disproving the Administration on a contract interpretation . I am quite certain The Administration would suggest I receive pre approval to wipe my buttocks...  I do think your suggested rewording is better then the status quo.  While I understand the majority of respondents are not going to be experts, I was seeking feedback from reasonable persons. Thank you all thus far

Comment: @user131366 I'm the most reasonable person in the world, but if you don't give the context of your question, I can't reason it out.   If you're working on a contract, you better have contract lawyers writing your proposed language.  Coming here with questions is worse than useless; it's dangerous.  Generally, what a good lawyer will do is insert in your contract a definitions section that clarifies terms like "scheduled day."  Run, don't walk, to his (or her) office.

Comment: @deadrat an employee was denied his holiday pay because he used an FMLA day using his comp. time  benefit to cover his absence the day prior to a holiday. Generally speaking FMLA is used for medical reasons thus falling into the sick day category, however the employee is able to use any benefit time they have accrued to cover the absence. The contract has already been written on holiday pay but the administration interprets the CBA to suit them even if it is not written as such.  Lawyers helped write the ambiguous language believe it or not.

Comment: @deadrat furthermore as the original full post mentions the contract language uses scheduled to define pre approved. The question is what does it modify? Does a excused sick day have to be scheduled as it is written?

Comment: I don't intent to sight information I received on stack exchange from a guy who goes by the name of deadrat as reasons to sway their decisions. I am curious as to what a non biased uninvolved party may feel.  Does an excused absence have to be scheduled to be pre approved based on the context of the language provided.

Comment: Yes, a pre-approved absence is defined as a certain type of scheduled day. So for one of those three types of absences to be considered pre-approved, it must be scheduled.